# Re-Size image in UIImagePicker im iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePicker to capture image from camera. My problem is I want to re-size the image with custom coordinate.

So let I have frame in which user can take a picture and I want to save ONLY that frame area. Ex: if I am taking picture of a person the frame is covering his face then I just need to save the face area not the background the other body portion.

The code which I am using is :
`

```
CGRect scaledRect = CGRectZero;
```

CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(  baseImage.size.width,baseImage.size.height);

```
scaledRect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
scaledRect.size.width  = baseImage.size.width;
scaledRect.size.height =  baseImage.size.height;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);    
[baseImage drawInRect:scaledRect];  

UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

return result;
```

`

One more question, Do I need to worry about device orientation too? If user is taking picture in landscape mode do I need to handle  this?

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find answer from [resize and crop image centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955189/resize-and-crop-image-centered).